# Why Steward badge is rewarded only once per review type?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, badges

So, the Steward badge is rewarded only once per review type. This is provoking reviewing other queues once they have reached the amount of 1000 reviews which is reasonable.

On the other hand, reviewing 1000 items takes considerable amount of time and efforts and, well, why not award continuing that work?

My suggestion is – allow to get Steward badge more than once per review type, but, to keep the motivation to check out other queues, award it for each **2000** reviews after the first 1000 (meaning the badge is given when one finishes 1000, 3000, 5000 etc reviews in one queue).

Let me know if I'm missing something in the reasoning above.

PS Now this is implemented, one gets a badge per each 1000 reviews.

Comment: _"Let me know if I'm missing something in the reasoning above."_: ___Why?___

Comment: I actually like the idea. Why not double the required reviews every time (1000, 3000, 6000, ...)?

Comment: @Cerbrus The why is relatively clear: To extend the gamification process in order to get more people to do reviews.

Comment: @BDL: I'd expect the __why__ to be explicit in a feature request.

Comment: If anything, I'd lower the requisite reviews for the Steward badges. 500 reviews are a lot of work anyway, and we'd be spared a lot of robo reviewing.

Comment: @Cerbrus the second paragraph addresses the why part (what BDL added gamification is valid) – basically it's the award-for-work suggestion

Comment: But why does it need a larger award? Gold badges shouldn't be farmable.

Comment: @Cerbrus well, they are farmable already.. (I mean, if I'm just a badge-hunter, I can already do 1000 useless reviews and get the badge) Anyway, I'm considering Servy's answer, that line of objection is understandable, although not that quite clear (in terms of resolution) to me.

Comment: Not farmable. You can get at most 1 per queue.

Comment: @Cerbrus it depends on your definition of "farmable". One can already get 3+ badges for 1000 clicks each.

Answer (score 14):

Oh please no.  This badge causes *so* many problems.  There are already way too many reviewers out there doing a truly awful job of reviewing because they're just there for the badge, and not to actually improve the quality of the content on the site.  As it is we have to sit through them doing a full 1000 bad reviews (per queue) before they leave.  Giving them a reason to stick around and *keep* doing their bad reviews forever would be just...terrible.

> On the other hand, reviewing 1000 items takes considerable amount of time and efforts

It does if you want to do the job well.  It doesn't when you just do reviews as fast as you possibly can for the sake of a badge, as a lot of people do.  The types of people putting in the time and effort are doing so because they already want to; because making the site better is its own reward.  Making this change won't result in them spending any more time, it'll just make their job that much harder as there'll be more people doing reviews for the sake of a badge.

Ideally the silver and gold badges would just be removed.  They caused *tons* of problems when they were first introduced (the bronze badge is great as it introduces people to the queue, and anyone interested in just gaming it won't case too much harm before getting the badge(s)).  SO has, unfortunately, been unwilling to do this.  Things go better when enough time past for the first wave of people trying to game this badge eventually got their 1000 reviews and left, and the people finding it later are small enough in number to be dealt with.  Let's not bring about another wave.

Comment: _Another wave_ which will not subside, as these ___gold___ badges would be handed out indefinitely.

Comment: How about a gold badge for completing 100 successful, *consecutive* review audits? :)

Comment: @DavidG The whole reason that so many problems result from bad reviewers is that it's just impossibly difficult to catch them when they do bad reviews much of the time.  There isn't enough overview of reviews for the bad reviews to be reliably noticed for that to work.

Comment: @Servy how about a review review queue?

Comment: @George Then we can have even *more* badges!!

Comment: Yeah, I was being slightly tongue-in-cheek with that comment, but if we had a decent audit system, it might just work...

Comment: @DavidG But we...don't.  And even if we *did* have a great audit system more (gold) badges still aren't going to attract the type of reviewers that we want.  The type of users we want to attract are the type of users *that don't care about badges*.

Comment: Right, I see the point. So the fundamental difference between badges given for nice/.. answers/questions and for reviews is that reviews are just done and almost nothing justifies their quality, isn't it? And the answer here is mostly a tactical one – unless the fundamental problem is solved, there's no point to give any more badges, right?